# DOMException Invalid key type from webcrypto importKey on RSA-PSS public key in spki DER

Tags: typescript, rsa, webcrypto-api

## Problem

I getting a strange errors when export a RSA-PSS public key from node with SPKI DER and import them with `importKey` of `webcrypto.subtle` to simulate the in-broweser context inside tests.

## Key generation at node

```js
                        generateKeyPair('rsa-pss' as any, {
                            modulusLength: algo.modulusLength.bits,
                            publicExponent: RSADefaultPublicExponentAsNumber,
                            hashAlgorithm: algo.hash || DigestAlgorithm.SHA512,
                            saltLength: algo.saltLength.bytes
                        }, processGeneratedKeys);
```

I omit parameters like `publicKeyEncoding` and `privateKeyEncoding` because these keys are for in-memory tests and these KeyObject instances will be used directly in the code below.

## Export of public key from Node:

```js
data = this.#impl.export({
                    type: "spki",
                    format: 'der'
                });
```

## Code to import with webcrypto

Below code to import the key from these DER-encoded SPKI bytes:

```js
                return await this.crypto.subtle.importKey('spki', memory, {
                    name: 'RSA-PSS',
                    hash: algo.hash,
                }, !!extractable, ["verify"]);
```

## Additional information

Same approach works for RSA keypair, generated as `rsa` and imported as `RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5` keys, in both directions (from browser to Node and back).
Even ECDSA keypair work with quite similar flow, but not RSA-PSS.

The `as any` things necessary to calm Typescript down. Alternative could be

```js
saltLength: algo.saltLength.bytes as any
```

because of broken definition of `RSAPSSKeyPairKeyObjectOptions` where `saltLength` is declared to be `string`.
But this is another issue, not impacting the problem I described above.

Thanks a lot for your attention and help.

Comment: I can reproduce the issue. The import fails for PSS with the webcrypto NodeJS integration (but is successful for PKCS#1), [here](https://replit.com/@3hK8cL8H24hwiS7/PrestigiousConstantMisrac#index.js). In contrast, the import with webcrypto in the browser is successful for PSS, [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3cnurha9/) (works with Firefox, but not with Chrome (which is a browser problem though)). This points to a bug in the webcrypto NodeJS integration. You could file a NodeJS issue for that.

Comment: @Topaco Your comment is so good it can be considered as an answer.